# Decompiling PyInstaller linux binary

Tags: pyinstaller, decompiling

I have a linux binary that was packed with PyInstaller that I need to decompress. The known tools like

https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor
https://github.com/pyinstxtractor/pyinstxtractor-ng
https://github.com/Mysterie/uncompyle2

have not lead to any success. Is there any known way to extract a linux binary?